# Regular Expression that matches a set of characters or nothing

Tags: regex, text-parsing

I have a set of text coming in as:

- 1 240R 15 Apr 2021 240 Litre Sulo Bin Recycling - Dkt#11053610 O/N: ONE DENTAL $10.00.
- 1 1.5cm 06 Apr 2021 1.5m Co-Mingle Recycling Bin - Dkt#11028471 $18.00.
- 1 1.5m 12 Apr 2021 Service 1.5m Front Lift bin - Dkt#11028421 $24.00
- 1 660 14 Apr 2021 660L Rear Lift Bin - Dkt#11156377 O/N: YOUR CAR SOLD $22.50

I am trying the regex: PCRE(PHP<7.3)

```
^(\d+) [^\$]+ (\d+ \w+ \d+) (\d.+ \w.+) \S (Dkt\S\d+)[^\$]+ (\$.*)$
```

Which parses the above However, I am unable to parse "O/N: ONE DENTAL" or "O/N: YOUR CAR SOLD" from the above list

How can I do it that if there is something after Dkt#xxxx it will also be parsed or nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you already have the pattern, I made a few slight modifications to it. This is based on the example strings provided and may need further modification if you have other variations of the rules used to match.

**[Example](https://regex101.com/r/BxISl9/1)**:

```
^(\d) (\S+) (\d{2} \w{3} \d{4}) (.*)\s+-\s(Dkt\S+)\s*(.*?)\s*(\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\.?\s*$
```

[image]